# Fitting data/determining parameter values for custom (biPareto) distribution

Tags: r, regression, fitting

I have a dataset containing information about a bunch of wireless devices.  Specifically, the number of other wireless devices each device encounters.  Based on other researcher's prior work in the same area, I have reason to believe my distribution may potentially be well fitted by the not so well known [biPareto distribution](ftp://netlib.bell-labs.com/who/nuzman/papers/nssw_TCP.pdf), whose CCDF is defined as:

$1 - F(x) = (x/k)^{-\alpha}(\frac{x+kb}{k + kb})^{\alpha-\beta}$, for $ x > k$

and simply

$1 - F(x) = 1$, for $x \le k$.

Assume I already know $k = 1$.  This leaves a function to fit with the three parameters $\alpha$,$b$,$\beta$, with the restriction that each parameter is $> 0$.

What I am unsure about is how one would go about determining the most suitable fitting parameter values, ideally in `R`.

I am quite the novice when it comes to fitting data, so aside from the syntactical considerations in `R`, I am also interested in any advice regarding what specific methods of fitting would be most appropriate for this particular function.  For example:

1. Does this function qualify for linear regression?
2. Is least squares appropriate/applicable here?  What about minimum mean squared error (MMSE)?
3. How sensitive is any given fitting method to any "guiding" initial parameter values I give it (iterative methods?), or is the result determined analytically (always produces the same answer in the end?)

If it's at all relevant, I'm ultimately looking to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on the data to see how well it matches the parameterized biPareto distribution.

Comment: I don't quite see how linear regression could help you estimate $\alpha, b, \beta$. I suppose least squares could help you to set of a moment-based estimating equation if you know the moments of this distribution as a function of $\alpha, b, \beta$, but I'd tend to go with maximum likelihood as the default choice. You have the CDF there, so you can get the log-likelihood easily and optimize it. Is there some reason you don't want to do that?